# iframe and JavaScript on different pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

If I was to have a page like `index.php` and then was to include an iframe, but the iframe was missing JavaScript that was included on the index.php file; would the JavaScript activate the JavaScript functions on the iframe or is it required for them to be on the same page?

Example:

Index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
```

Includes both of the following code, while the iframe requires them but does not have it listed on the page.

Comment: you have to reference the scripts on the page which is loaded by the iframe.
And explain a bit more...
Do you need access to the script functions in the page loaded by the iframe?

Comment: @legends Is there any possible way that I can achieve that I am trying to do? Because for the task I am working on it will not work unless I can make this possible some how

Comment: Please explain what you are wanting to do in more detail. Also important to know if iframe will be same domain or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript environments of the main page and the iframe are separate, but if they come from the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), they can talk to each other.

This means you have two options:

1. Include the scripts in the HTML for both the main page and the iframe; this is simplest
2. If they're in the same origin, the main page can make its functions available in the iframe's environment like this (assume `functionName` is a function in the main page):

   ```
   theIframe.contentWindow.functionName = functionName;
   ```

   That shares `functionName` with the iframe (making it a global function in the iframe). Note that `functionName` is still in the main page's environment, so for instance, in that function's code, `document` will refer to the main page's document, not the iframe's.

Comment: Thank you so much bro! This helped a lot and solved my issue, glad to see someone under stood what I was trying to say in as few words as possible.

Comment: @Lee Yep. I once did it like this with jquery, IIRC: `<iframe onload="if (typeof $ != 'undefined') this.contentWindow.$ = $; if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') this.contentWindow.jQuery = jQuery; "`. This remove the necessity of including the same .js file in the iframes. Though I will bet there are some edge cases where this might fail. (For example, if you do something very context specific, or before the onload fires.)